How do I handle ActiveStorage::PreviewError for failed PDF preview?
I'm using ActiveStorage on Rails 6.1 to do file uploads with previews. When a user uploads a PDF it generates a preview fine but if the PDF requires a password it fails with ActiveStorage::PreviewError How do I deal with that so it doesn't raise an error and responds that the file.previewable? is false instead of true?

previewable? only checks to see if there is a registered Previewer for the file type. I guess you could modify this to check if the file is previewable and then try and preview it (rescuing the error) but this would be highly inefficient since previewing involves downloading the file. You could also consider checking whether or not the PDF has a password when it is uploaded and storing something in your own tables that indicates whether or not it is previewable

Thanks, maybe previewable? isn't the place to catch this then.
